# How to extract python output out of the cmd?

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

I am using cmd in Windows 7 and I have encounter the following problem:

I write the command `python` in cmd to enter my code in python, then follows:

```
import requests
r=requests.get("https://nameofthepege.com")
r.text
```

After that the whole console gets full of hmtl code. The last 200 to 300 linesof the output are visible but the rest are not. How can I see more lines?

Moreover, is there any way to extract the html code produced by the `r.text`command in a new file from within the python environment or the cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question.

> After that the whole console gets full of html code. The last 200 to
>   300 lines of the output are visible but the rest are not. How can I
>   see more lines?

**Response:** The CMD default buffer is limited to 300 lines. You should increase the CMD prompt buffer size.

The below tutorial explains how to do that:

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/94089-change-command-prompt-screen-buffer-size-windows.html

Regarding your second question.

> Moreover, is there any way to extract the html code produced by the
>   r.text command in a new file from within the python environment or the
>   cmd?

**Response:** You can write the content from `r.text` into a file by creating a file with Python `open()` function. More information about *Reading and Writing Files* in the below link:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files